# visual statistics: fractions of people

Tags: r, data-visualization

Are there any packages/functions in R to plot visual fractions of people (for frequencies, probabilities, etc)?

Examples of the kind of plots I would like to make in R (static, without the interactivity):

http://understandinguncertainty.org/visualfraction
http://understandinguncertainty.org/balance

Thanks for any help.

Comment: These charts are called [isotype or Neurath charts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99385/is-there-a-name-for-bar-charts-that-replace-the-bars-with-color-coded-objects/99410?s=1|0.3736#99410) or sometimes pictogram charts. There have been several discussions of doing them in R ([1](http://www.r-bloggers.com/easy-pictograms-using-r/), [2](http://www.r-bloggers.com/pre-cran-waffle-update-isotype-pictograms/)) but I don't know if any do the fractional-images automatically.

Comment: See also [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401806/wanted-repeated-pictogram-visualization-of-population-split) (scroll down!). One could of course construct images that represent say tenths of a picture (0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9) and use those -- more accuracy than that is probably wasted.